# Do I have to put a "var" in front of an argument if it's not passed in by the callee in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function `dosomething` and I call it sometimes with an argument, sometimes without.

I want to let the default value of the argument equals 5. So I have these two ways:

```
function dosomething(a) {
  if(!a) {
    a = 5;
  }
}
```

Or

```
function dosomething(a) {
  if(!a) {
    var a = 5;
  }
}
```

After testing I found they both work.

But do I have to use the `var`? What's the difference?

Comment: `var` declares a variable. Function arguments are already declared. See also... [_"Duplicate variable declarations using var will not trigger an error, even in strict mode, and the variable will not lose its value, unless another assignment is performed."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description)

Comment: using `var` will declare a new variable and sets the value of the new variable to `5` but using only `a` doesnt declare any new variable, it sets the value of the parameter to `5`

Comment: As ESLint `[no-redeclare][1]` rule describes:
```
In JavaScript, it's possible to redeclare the same variable name using var. This can lead to confusion as to where the variable is actually declared and initialized.
```
So better declare var only one time for a specific variable.

In ES6 u can do a default value like this:
```
function print (a = 10) {
    
}
```

> Besides use `let` instead `var` in function


  [1]: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare